# why is an open faithfully-flat morphism fpqc?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Why is an open faithfully-flat morphism fpqc?

In other words, why must an open faithfully flat morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ have the property that around every $x\in X$, there is an open nbhd $U$ of $x\in X$ such that $f(U)$ is open, and the restriction of $f$ to $U\rightarrow f(U)$ is quasi-compact?

thanks,

- will

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39211, there Qing Liu has answered this question.